# ajax call fails when i try to create a new table php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Want to send a ajax request to php to create a new table dynamically. I have the following code:

**Javascript:**

```
var file = $('#'+option_file_name.id).prop('files')[0];
var form_data = new FormData(); 
form_data.append('file', file);
form_data.append('column_name', option_file_name.id.slice(12));
send_ajax_request(form_data);

function send_ajax_request(pdata){
    console.log(pdata);
    $.ajax({
        url: "set_points_data.php",
        data: pdata,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'post',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(a,b,c){
            alert("something went wrong");
        }
    });
}
```

**php script:**

in the data.php file i connect to the database and have all the supporting functions.

```
<?php
include 'data.php';

$data = null;

if(isset($_FILES)){
    $data = $_FILES;
    $type = (string)$_POST["column_name"];
    create_table($conn, $type);
    return_ajax("succes");
}else{
    return_ajax("error");
}

function create_table($conn, $name){
    send_sql($conn, "CREATE TABLE `".$name."` (
        options varchar(255));"
    );
}
?>
```

UPDATE:

it turns out that if i change the following code to this the error disappears. see the new code below:

```
send_sql($conn, "CREATE TABLE testTable (
    options varchar(255)
);");
```

but this is not what i want i need to create tables dynamically.

when ever i run run the ajax request i get the error something went wrong. 
But when i run the php script without the ajax call it works fine. 
and when i run the php script from the ajax call but without the create table function it also works fine. So i am not sure what is happening here. 
Hope this is clear if not let me know.

Comment: What you are passing in ajax call??

Comment: see updated question, but the data is not the problem. the ajax call works fine with the data, but fails when i try to create a table in the php script.

Comment: This is just asking for a SQL injection attack. Never insert unsanitised data into your SQL directly in this way. Check first that the value you're using is acceptable (and not an attempt to terminate the real query, and run a DELETE or DROP command instead, just to give one possible example).

Comment: "i am not sure what is happening here" In that case, check your real error (in the browser's console and/or the ajax request in the network tab), not just the one you made up to put in the alert. If you don't understand what it says, please post it in your question so we can help. If the code is going into the "error" callback, then chances are your server returned a HTTP error status code (i.e. not 200 OK) so it would be useful to know that too.

Comment: I notice also that the JS is sending a file variable, which the PHP is ignoring. If you're not going to use a variable on the server-side, then don't bother sending it from the client.

Comment: oke thanks for the suggestion. after doing some more testing i figured out it was actually adding the table to the database. But the AJAX call keeps returning something went wrong. I will check your suggestions to see if i can get some more clarity on what is going wrong.

Comment: i dont get any error codes. Not in the console, or the network tab. not sure what is happening :P

Comment: i updated the question maybe this gives more insight.

Comment: if it's returning into the "error" callback, then it's impossible that nothing is logged. Depending on your browser, there might nothing in the console. But what status code is the ajax request returning? Also what does your return_ajax() PHP function do? There might be a clue in there.

Comment: just a little remark : `isset()` returns `true` if the variable is set and `false` if the variable is not set, writing `isset($var) != null` is a bit weird

Comment: yeah you are right. I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some testing i figured out that ajax is trying to return some data after doing the create table statement. Resulting in a error. if you change it to the following.

```
if(isset($_POST)){
    $data = $_FILES;
    $db_name = $_POST["tblname"];
    return_ajax(create_table($conn, $db_name));
}else{
    return_ajax("error");
}

function create_table($conn, $name){
    send_sql($conn, "CREATE TABLE `".$name."` (
        options varchar(255)
    );");
    return "database created";
}
```

This wil work. not sure what exactly happens but this fixes the ajax error.